# gmake include target file based on build target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, target

I have a Makefile and then targets.mk files in subfolders.

I want to build one of the sub target files based on a command line build target.

'make  plugin'

if I try something like this in Makefile, it does not build the target.mk in the subfolder

```
plugin: BUILD_PLUGIN=Yes
all:    libraries binaries

ifeq($(BUILD_PLUGIN),Yes
    include subfolder/targets.mk
endif
```

Anyone know how I can do this?  I don't seem to have much luck using MAKECMDGOALS either.

The contents of targets.mk is this:

```
PLUGIN_SRCDIR=myplugin
PLUGIN_CPP_SRCS=\
    $(PLUGIN_SRCDIR)/coder.cpp\

PLUGIN_OBJS += $(PLUGIN_CPP_SRCS:.cpp=.o)

OBJS += $(PLUGIN_OBJS)
$(PLUGIN_SRCDIR)/%.o: $(PLUGIN_SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    $(QUIET_CXX)$(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(PLUGIN_CFLAGS) $(PLUGIN_INCLUDES) -c $(CXX_O) $<

$(LIBPREFIX)myplugin.$(LIBSUFFIX): $(PLUGIN_OBJS)
    $(QUIET)rm -f $@
    $(QUIET_AR)$(AR) $(AR_OPTS) $+

libraries: $(LIBPREFIX)myplugin.$(LIBSUFFIX)
LIBRARIES += $(LIBPREFIX)myplugin.$(LIBSUFFIX)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the rule for `subfolder/targets.mk`?

Comment: What do you mean?  I added the contents of targets.mk

Comment: Do you want your makefile to build `subfolder/targets.mk`?

Comment: yes I do, but I need to keep a separate Make file and  subfolder/targets.mk file

Comment: Then your makefile must have a rule to build `subfolder/targets.mk`. Can I assume that such a rule exists in your makefile?

Comment: The rule is in targets.mk  see 'libraries:'                      There is also this in Makefile.  'all:    libraries binaries'  which causes libraries to get build.  Thing is I only want the rule in targets.mk to get called when I use the 'plugin' target on the commandline.

Comment: Last try: you **don't** want your makefile to **build** `subfolder/targets.mk`, you want it to *run the `libraries` rule in that file* when you call `make plugin`. Is... that... correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct, run that rule when I call make plugin.

Comment: And not run the libraries rule when I do not specify make plugin

Answer (score 0):

The following Makefile will build the subfolder upon command `make plugin`:

```
all: libraries binaries
plugin:
    $(MAKE) -C subfolder -f targets.mk
libraries binaries:
    echo building $@
```

I have not paid any attention to the libraries and binaries targets. However it still makes the all target per default. As the first target is the default target you need to place a target that does nothing as the first target if specifying nothing shall do nothing.